# Who were parents of Johann Gottlieb Drange (b.1850 or 1851)

Tags: 19th-century, germany, birth-records

Johann Gottlieb Drange birthplace is given variously as Darschäwitz, Possen or Posen(possibly misspelled Preußen?), Germany, July 1850. The 1900 US Census lists him as “Jno G. Drange” of Cullom Village, Livingston Co., IL. and gives 1882 as date of immigration (but 1880 in the 1910 census, where he is shown as John G. Drange).

How might I find out who his parents were?

Family tradition says his father was a military officer, but we don’t know anything more.

Comment: Welcome to Genealogy & Family History SE! What evidence do you have for birth and immigration dates? It seems unlikely for a 40 year old man to be emigrating because of parental pressure in career choice! Do you have any clues to narrow down a birth location? Posen was large.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Please try to ask a single focussed question rather than two like you have here.  You can use the [edit] button to remove one of them and provide more details as background to it.  Feel free to ask the other question separately via the Ask Question button.

Comment: Stan, thanks for editing your question - much more focussed now. I've reopened so hopefully you'll get some answers soon. I'm assuming the date of immigration on the 1910 census is 1900 not 1800?

Comment: If you have a digital copy of the original record(s), it might be useful to upload. The person's name is German, but the location sounds slavic (Polish). I am very suspicious of the "ä", and to some extent of the first "a" as weli. Posen (now Poznan) is a city in Poland, so I would first look for places near there that have a name similar to Derschewitz, Derzvice or similar.

Comment: Place referenced is most likly Darsewitz, Usedom-Wollin, Stettin, Pommern [now Darzowice, Poland], according to both Meyers Orts and GOV. But lots of Dranges in Posen according to Family Search, in Unruhstadt and Karge, both in former Kreis Bomst, and other places.

Comment: A new clue: manifest of S.S. Wieland shows a “Gottl Drange” on board in Hamburg, 2 June 1880, arrived New York 15 June.  Age 29.  That fits his birth date of 24 July 1880.  Gottl is an accepted abbreviation of Gottlieb.  A presenter at a 1991 Drange family reunion claimed he had sisters named Olga Drange and Caroline Kretchmer born Drange.  Thanks bgwiehle for the ideas on birthplace. Still nothing definitive found on that.

Comment: Solved. I got his birth record from the State Archive in Poznań, poland.  He was born 24 July 1850 in Daszewice, near Poznań.  Parents were Joh. August Drange and Julienne Döhring, who had a small farm.  His paternal grandparents were Joh. Gottlieb (or Gottlob) Drange, master miller in Daszewice, and Anna Rosina Guntsch.